# NiFi load results of mysql query into attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm doing a simple row count query using an ExecuteSQL processor. I need to route flow based on the value. Currently, in addition to the ExecuteSQL processor, I need to use ConvertAvroToJSON AND EvaluateJsonPath to get the value. I was hoping I could reduce the complexity of the flow, since I have to do this in many places all over the canvas.

I've been trying to read the avro (as emitted from ExecuteSQL) using ${json.field_name} (recommended by chatgpt) but the result is always empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a `ExecuteSQLRecord` processor with JsonRecordSetWriter and then `EvaluateJsonPath` processor

Comment: @tonykoval thank you. My flow file's contents is now `[{"cnt":1}]` and using EvaluateJsonPath my property called `row_count` is set to `$.cnt` but the attribute `row_count` is empty on the output flow file?

Comment: @tonykoval After debugging I detected that the Array Grouping must be switched off on the JsonRecordSetWriter - it works now! Thank you. Please add an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ExecuteSQLRecord` processor with `JsonRecordSetWriter` and then `EvaluateJsonPath` processor.